# Creating a new Day Partitioned table doesn't have a schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I've tried many ways to create a partitioned table and add data to it but I have yet to create one with a valid schema or be able to update it with a valid schema.

1) I've tried to create it from a set of tables with a date suffix - this creates the table and seems to add data to it but it has no schema and therefore cannot be queried.

2) I've tried to create a table with a schema but this ends up with no schema

3) I've tried to create a table and then add data to try and infer a schema but this doesn't work either.

Anyone had any success with these tables?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for reporting the issue.

1. If you tried copying from date suffixed tables to a partitioned table using bq partition command -- bq partition command has a bug that has since been fixed. We are waiting for an SDK release for the fix to be live.
2. In your test, I'm curious how the data was added to the partitioned table? Was it through a copy or through a load job? For example, the following should keep the schema:

   bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY myproject:mydataset.mytable

   bq cp myproject:mydataset.mynonpartitionedtable 'myproject:mydataset.mytable$20160106'

Comment: Hi Pavan 
It was through the bq insert command that I tried to add data to the table. I'm fairly certain the docs said somewhere that it would infer a schema from the first insert.
Cheers

Comment: bq insert streams data into a table and I believe it requires the table to have a schema. Automatic schema inference on first load works for load. If you could point me to the documentation where you might have seen this, I can take a further look. Thanks!